# How Lucene caches filter using the segment state?

Tags: java, caching, search, lucene

In the current implementation, a query/filter cache seems to be invalidated when the `IndexReader` is reopened after a new change is committed into the index.

The key of a cache returned by `org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader#getCoreCacheKey` is a reference to `SegmentCoreReaders` which is re-recreated when we reopen the `IndexReader`.

How can Lucene keep a cache key of an existing segment unchanged ?

Comment: Cache is per segment, perhaps your problem resides is how you re-open your reader? Do you use DirectoryReader.openIfChanged() or ReaderManager?

Comment: As you said, the `DirectoryReader.openIfChanged() ` doesn't create a new reference to `SegmentCoreReaders` if the segment hasn't been changed.